# Variable "entry" does not exist - error on homepage single entry

Tags: craft3, templating

Relatively new to CraftCMS and getting Twig error "Variable "entry" does not exist" on my home page.

Noticed another post said to leave URI blank which should fix but didn't.

Just looking to output something very simple i.e. {{ entry.featureHeading }}

Appears to not be recognising the home page as an entry but it is and is setup as a 'single'

Comment: On the single's settings page have you ticked the 'home' checkbox under site settings?

Comment: Yep, have ticked the 'home' icon checkbox